# Unstable behavior of dynamically allocated LPTSTR (TCHAR*) and delete[] operator?

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, dynamic

I was trying to build a class that deal with String operators. However, for no convincing reason, it sometime crashed during delete[] operator. I used strsafe library to do all internal string operation.

//qstring

```
LPTSTR m_string;

void QString::operator +=(const QString &_in) //Concat m_string with _in.m_string
{
    size_t size = strlength(m_string) + strlength(_in.m_string) +1; //new size
    LPTSTR buffer = new TCHAR[size]; //alloc buffer
    ::StringCchCopy(buffer,strlength(m_string)+1,m_string); //copy current m_string to buffer

    ::StringCchCat(buffer, size, _in.m_string); //concat buffer with the input

    Replace(buffer); //replace this object with m_string

    delete[] buffer; //dealloc
}


void QString::Replace(LPCTSTR src) //replace m_string with src
{
    size_t size = strlength(src)+1; //new size
    Alloc(size);
    ::StringCchCopy(m_string,size,src); //copy src to m_string
}


void QString::Alloc(size_t size) //Dynamic allocation
{
    if(m_string != NULL) Free();
    m_string = new TCHAR[size+1];
}


void QString::Free()  //Free m_string
{
        delete[] m_string; //Sometime crashes here
        m_string = NULL;
}


QString ToStr(int _in) //Convert Integer to qstring
{
    int size = 1;
    int f = _in;

    while(f > 0)
    {
        f /=10;
        size++;
    }

    TCHAR* buf = new TCHAR[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) buf[i] = (TCHAR)TEXT("");

    QString result(L"undef");

    if(::_itow_s(_in,buf,size,10) == 0) //No error code = ok 
    {
        result = buf;
    }
    delete[] buf;
    return result;
}
```

//Example 1: Does not crashed

```
int ::WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    QString a(L"");
    a += L"TEST";
    a += ToStr(1000);

::MessageBox(0,a.GetStr(),L"NOTHING",MB_OK);

        return 0;
}
```

//Example 2: Print weird characters plus some of the current characters (Unicode problems?)

```
 int ::WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    QString a(L"");
    a += L"TESTTESTESTEST";
    a += ToStr(1000);
    ::MessageBox(0,a.GetStr(),L"NOTHING",MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

//Example 3: Crashes on load

```
int ::WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    QString a(L"");
    a += L"TESTTESTESTEST";
    a += ToStr(1000);
    a += L"TESTESTEST";
    a += ToStr(100);
    ::MessageBox(0,a.GetStr(),L"NOTHING",MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

It crashed on delete[] operator in Free(). With error of either

HEAP[StringTest.exe]: Invalid Address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 003C0000, 003C46A8 )

or

HEAP[StringTest.exe]: Heap block at 003C4750 modified at 003C475C past requested size of 4

Comment: What does QString's constructor look like?

Comment: QString's constructor calls Replace()

Comment: Just a small side note - you should never declare variables starting with an underscore. [That naming style is reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @eran: strictly speaking, underscore followed by a lowercase letter is only reserved in the global namespace - it's not reserved when used for a local name. However, I'd still agree that leading underscore should be avoided (unless you know enough to be able to justify exactly why you should use it).

Answer (score 1):

You constructor doesn't initialize m_string to NULL (according to your own comment above). This is causing random Free() failures.

As selbie notes, there are other bugs and inefficiencies in this code. For example, Replace always reallocates, even when called from += that has already allocated. And you add 1 in both Replace and Alloc, suggesting you are not clear about which functions take values that include the terminator and which don't.

Unless this is a learning or homework exercise, I strongly recommend against writing your own string class - it will take you a lot more work to get something reasonable and efficient than it would to use std::string (or ATL::CString if you prefer).

Martyn

Comment: I think this is right - I still find it somewhat irritating that the ctor was only 'described' instead of being posted (especially after being asked for it). People should realize that *precise* details matter in these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer:

My psychic powers tells me that if QString doesn't have a copy constructor, then bad things are likely happening when ToStr() returns a "copy" of a QString on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I see lots of bugs.

For starters, if you pass in 0 to the ToStr function, you will only allocated one char of memory to hold the string "0" which is two bytes ('0' + null char).  Further, if you pass a negative integer into this function, other bad things will happen.  You are better off just allocating more than you need without trying to compute the "exact" size.

```
int size = sizeof(_in) * 4 + 1;
```

None of your strcpy's (even with using the StringCch functions) make me feel good.

I would suggest allocating 2x the amount of "size" you need, then carefully study the memory address of buffer and m_string via debugging if the strcpy goes beyond "size-1" bytes (not including the null terminating char).

Comment: So the strcpy needs reserved space for safety? Ok, but I did exact size, because I don't want it to eat too much space in the heap (Just being conservative)

Comment: The memory overhead the c-runtime incurs for allocating a small buffer large enough to hold an integer string is likely larger than the integer string itself!  Since you are immediately releasing it, theres nothing to be gained.  And if you want to be even FASTER, don't allocate the temp buffer at all. Just use the stack.  "char buffer[sizeof(_in)*4+1];"

Answer (score 0):

your whole Allocation and free algorithms are predicated on the fact that m_string has been initialized to NULL.  Have you done that in your constructor (I don't see it here)?

by the way, you may have a conflict with a CRT library function named Alloc().
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492420%28VS.100%29.aspx

your algorithm for calculating the length of an integer string is incorrect.  you start out with size=1, you should start out with size=0.  also, you need to handle the special case where 0==f: 0 is definitely a number and takes up 1 character.  you had an off-by-1 error (fencepost error) where the size of the integer was always 1 too big.

```
QString ToStr(int _in) //Convert Integer to qstring
{
    int size = 0;
    int f = _in;

    if (0==f) {
        size=1;
    } else {
        while(f > 0) {
            f /=10;
            size++;
        }
    }
```

in Replace(), you Alloc() 2 extra characters.

```
size_t size = strlength(src)+1;
```

should be

```
size_t size = strlength(src);
```

and if you need an extra character for the ::StringCchCopy(m_string,size,src); put in size+1 there.  or else change your Alloc so it allocates exactly the number of characters you ask for (like the name implies).